# Jupyter-notebook exploding after command conda install -c conda-forge

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, conda

I hope this post brings you well.  I have environment issues that I would love to get assistance on.

I installed geopandas with command: 
`conda install -c conda-forge geopandas`

Then typed `jupyter-notebook` and got a nasty error, here is what it reads:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mathlizard/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 10, in 
    import sqlite3
  File "/home/mathlizard/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/sqlite3/**init**.py", line 23, in 
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/home/mathlizard/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in 
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: libncurses.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mathlizard/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 7, in 
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "/home/mathlizard/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 84, in 
    from .services.sessions.sessionmanager import SessionManager
  File "/home/mathlizard/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 13, in 
    from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysqlite2'

**My attempts**

- wrote the following commands:

  - `pip install pysqlite2`
  - `pip install libsqlite3-dev`
  - `sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev`
  - `pip install pysqlite`
  - `conda install pysqlite2`
  - `conda install pysqlite`
- created and edited .condarc file in root directory with following lines of code:

channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults

**UPDATES**

- installed pysqlite with `conda install -c kbchoi pysqlite` and now the error after typing `jupyter-notebook` is the following:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mathlizard/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 7, in 
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "/home/mathlizard/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 85, in 
    from .services.sessions.sessionmanager import SessionManager
  File "/home/mathlizard/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 13, in 
    from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
  File "/home/mathlizard/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysqlite2/dbapi2.py", line 28, in 
    from pysqlite2._sqlite import *
ImportError: libncurses.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

**Background info:**

- `which python` outputs this: /home/mathlizard/anaconda3/bin/python
- `which jupyter` outputs this: /home/mathlizard/anaconda3/bin/jupyter
- my .bashrc file contains these lines of code: `export PATH="/home/mathlizard/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"`

  and `export PATH="/home/mathlizard/anaconda2/bin:$PATH"`
- `conda list` generates:

  ## Name                    Version                   Build  Channel

_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf    0.1.0            py27h08a7f0c_0
alabaster                 0.7.10           py27he5a193a_0
anaconda                  5.2.0                    py27_3
anaconda-client           1.6.14                   py27_0
anaconda-navigator        1.8.7                    py27_0
anaconda-project          0.8.2            py27h236b58a_0
asn1crypto                0.24.0                   py27_0
astroid                   1.6.3                    py27_0
astropy                   2.0.6            py27h3010b51_1
attrs                     18.1.0                   py27_0
babel                     2.5.3                    py27_0
backports                 1.0              py27h63c9359_1
backports.functools_lru_cache 1.5                      py27_1
backports.shutil_get_terminal_size 1.0.0            py27h5bc021e_2
backports_abc             0.5              py27h7b3c97b_0
beautifulsoup4            4.6.0            py27h3f86ba9_1
bitarray                  0.8.1            py27h14c3975_1
bkcharts                  0.2              py27h241ae91_0
blas                      1.0                         mkl
blaze                     0.11.3           py27h5f341da_0
bleach                    2.1.3                    py27_0
blosc                     1.14.3               hdbcaa40_0
bokeh                     0.12.16                  py27_0
boto                      2.48.0           py27h9556ac2_1
bottleneck                1.2.1            py27h21b16a3_0
bzip2                     1.0.6                h14c3975_5
ca-certificates           2018.03.07                    0
cairo                     1.14.12              h7636065_2
cdecimal                  2.3              py27h14c3975_3
certifi                   2018.4.16                py27_0
cffi                      1.11.5           py27h9745a5d_0
chardet                   3.0.4            py27hfa10054_1
click                     6.7              py27h4225b90_0
cloudpickle               0.5.3                    py27_0
clyent                    1.2.2            py27h7276e6c_1
colorama                  0.3.9            py27h5cde069_0
conda                     4.5.11                   py27_0
conda-build               3.10.5                   py27_0
conda-env                 2.6.0                h36134e3_1
conda-verify              2.0.0            py27hf052a9d_0
configparser              3.5.0            py27h5117587_0
contextlib2               0.5.5            py27hbf4c468_0
cryptography              2.2.2            py27h14c3975_0
curl                      7.60.0               h84994c4_0
cycler                    0.10.0           py27hc7354d3_0
cython                    0.28.2           py27h14c3975_0
cytoolz                   0.9.0.1          py27h14c3975_0
dask                      0.17.5                   py27_0
dask-core                 0.17.5                   py27_0
datashape                 0.5.4            py27hf507385_0
dbus                      1.13.2               h714fa37_1
decorator                 4.3.0                    py27_0
distributed               1.21.8                   py27_0
docutils                  0.14             py27hae222c1_0
entrypoints               0.2.3            py27h502b47d_2
enum34                    1.1.6            py27h99a27e9_1
et_xmlfile                1.0.1            py27h75840f5_0
expat                     2.2.5                he0dffb1_0
fastcache                 1.0.2            py27h14c3975_2
filelock                  3.0.4                    py27_0
flask                     1.0.2                    py27_1
flask-cors                3.0.4                    py27_0
fontconfig                2.12.6               h49f89f6_0
freetype                  2.8                  hab7d2ae_1
funcsigs                  1.0.2            py27h83f16ab_0
functools32               3.2.3.2          py27h4ead58f_1
futures                   3.2.0            py27h7b459c0_0
get_terminal_size         1.0.0                haa9412d_0
gevent                    1.3.0            py27h14c3975_0
glib                      2.56.1               h000015b_0
glob2                     0.6              py27hcea9cbd_0
gmp                       6.1.2                h6c8ec71_1
gmpy2                     2.0.8            py27h4cf3fa8_2
graphite2                 1.3.11               h16798f4_2
greenlet                  0.4.13           py27h14c3975_0
grin                      1.2.1                    py27_4
gst-plugins-base          1.14.0               hbbd80ab_1
gstreamer                 1.14.0               hb453b48_1
h5py                      2.7.1            py27ha1f6525_2
harfbuzz                  1.7.6                h5f0a787_1
hdf5                      1.10.2               hba1933b_1
heapdict                  1.0.0                    py27_2
html5lib                  1.0.1            py27h5233db4_0
icu                       58.2                 h9c2bf20_1
idna                      2.6              py27h5722d68_1
imageio                   2.3.0                    py27_0
imagesize                 1.0.0                    py27_0
intel-openmp              2018.0.0                      8
ipaddress                 1.0.22                   py27_0
ipykernel                 4.8.2                    py27_0
ipython                   5.7.0                    py27_0
ipython_genutils          0.2.0            py27h89fb69b_0
ipywidgets                7.2.1                    py27_0
isort                     4.3.4                    py27_0
itsdangerous              0.24             py27hb8295c1_1
jbig                      2.1                  hdba287a_0
jdcal                     1.4                      py27_0
jedi                      0.12.0                   py27_1
jinja2                    2.10             py27h4114e70_0
jpeg                      9b                   h024ee3a_2
jsonschema                2.6.0            py27h7ed5aa4_0
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py27_4
jupyter_client            5.2.3                    py27_0
jupyter_console           5.2.0            py27hc6bee7e_1
jupyter_core              4.4.0            py27h345911c_0
jupyterlab                0.32.1                   py27_0
jupyterlab_launcher       0.10.5                   py27_0
kiwisolver                1.0.1            py27hc15e7b5_0
lazy-object-proxy         1.3.1            py27h682c727_0
libcurl                   7.60.0               h1ad7b7a_0
libedit                   3.1.20170329         h6b74fdf_2
libffi                    3.2.1                hd88cf55_4
libgcc-ng                 7.2.0                hdf63c60_3
libgfortran-ng            7.2.0                hdf63c60_3
libpng                    1.6.34               hb9fc6fc_0
libsodium                 1.0.16               h1bed415_0
libssh2                   1.8.0                h9cfc8f7_4
libstdcxx-ng              7.2.0                hdf63c60_3
libtiff                   4.0.9                he85c1e1_1
libtool                   2.4.6                h544aabb_3
libxcb                    1.13                 h1bed415_1
libxml2                   2.9.8                h26e45fe_1
libxslt                   1.1.32               h1312cb7_0
llvmlite                  0.23.1           py27hdbcaa40_0
locket                    0.2.0            py27h73929a2_1
lxml                      4.2.1            py27h23eabaa_0
lzo                       2.10                 h49e0be7_2
markupsafe                1.0              py27h97b2822_1
matplotlib                2.2.2            py27h0e671d2_1
mccabe                    0.6.1            py27h0e7c7be_1
mistune                   0.8.3            py27h14c3975_1
mkl                       2018.0.2                      1
mkl-service               1.1.2            py27hb2d42c5_4
mkl_fft                   1.0.1            py27h3010b51_0
mkl_random                1.0.1            py27h629b387_0
more-itertools            4.1.0                    py27_0
mpc                       1.0.3                hec55b23_5
mpfr                      3.1.5                h11a74b3_2
mpmath                    1.0.0            py27h9669132_2
msgpack-python            0.5.6            py27h6bb024c_0
multipledispatch          0.5.0                    py27_0
navigator-updater         0.2.1                    py27_0
nbconvert                 5.3.1            py27he041f76_0
nbformat                  4.4.0            py27hed7f2b2_0
ncurses                   6.1                  hf484d3e_0
networkx                  2.1                      py27_0
nltk                      3.3.0                    py27_0
nose                      1.3.7            py27heec2199_2
notebook                  5.5.0                    py27_0
numba                     0.38.0           py27h637b7d7_0
numexpr                   2.6.5            py27h7bf3b9c_0
numpy                     1.14.3           py27hcd700cb_1
numpy-base                1.14.3           py27h9be14a7_1
numpydoc                  0.8.0                    py27_0
odo                       0.5.1            py27h9170de3_0
olefile                   0.45.1                   py27_0
openpyxl                  2.5.3                    py27_0
openssl                   1.0.2o               h20670df_0
packaging                 17.1                     py27_0
pandas                    0.23.0           py27h637b7d7_0
pandoc                    1.19.2.1             hea2e7c5_1
pandocfilters             1.4.2            py27h428e1e5_1
pango                     1.41.0               hd475d92_0
parso                     0.2.0                    py27_0
partd                     0.3.8            py27h4e55004_0
patchelf                  0.9                  hf79760b_2
path.py                   11.0.1                   py27_0
pathlib2                  2.3.2                    py27_0
patsy                     0.5.0                    py27_0
pcre                      8.42                 h439df22_0
pep8                      1.7.1                    py27_0
pexpect                   4.5.0                    py27_0
pickleshare               0.7.4            py27h09770e1_0
pillow                    5.1.0            py27h3deb7b8_0
pip                       10.0.1                   py27_0
pixman                    0.34.0               hceecf20_3
pkginfo                   1.4.2                    py27_1
pluggy                    0.6.0            py27h1f4f128_0
ply                       3.11                     py27_0
prompt_toolkit            1.0.15           py27h1b593e1_0
psutil                    5.4.5            py27h14c3975_0
ptyprocess                0.5.2            py27h4ccb14c_0
py                        1.5.3                    py27_0
pycairo                   1.15.4           py27h1b9232e_1
pycodestyle               2.4.0                    py27_0
pycosat                   0.6.3            py27ha4109ae_0
pycparser                 2.18             py27hefa08c5_1
pycrypto                  2.6.1            py27h14c3975_8
pycurl                    7.43.0.1         py27hb7f436b_0
pyflakes                  1.6.0            py27h904a57d_0
pygments                  2.2.0            py27h4a8b6f5_0
pylint                    1.8.4                    py27_0
pyodbc                    4.0.23           py27hf484d3e_0
pyopenssl                 18.0.0                   py27_0
pyparsing                 2.2.0            py27hf1513f8_1
pyqt                      5.9.2            py27h751905a_0
pysocks                   1.6.8                    py27_0
pytables                  3.4.3            py27h02b9ad4_2
pytest                    3.5.1                    py27_0
python                    2.7.15               h1571d57_0
python-dateutil           2.7.3                    py27_0
pytz                      2018.4                   py27_0
pywavelets                0.5.2            py27hecda097_0
pyyaml                    3.12             py27h2d70dd7_1
pyzmq                     17.0.0           py27h14c3975_1
qt                        5.9.5                h7e424d6_0
qtawesome                 0.4.4            py27hd7914c3_0
qtconsole                 4.3.1            py27hc444b0d_0
qtpy                      1.4.1                    py27_0
readline                  7.0                  ha6073c6_4
requests                  2.18.4           py27hc5b0589_1
rope                      0.10.7           py27hfe459b0_0
ruamel_yaml               0.15.35          py27h14c3975_1
scandir                   1.7              py27h14c3975_0
scikit-image              0.13.1           py27h14c3975_1
scikit-learn              0.19.1           py27h445a80a_0
scipy                     1.1.0            py27hfc37229_0
seaborn                   0.8.1            py27h633ea1e_0
send2trash                1.5.0                    py27_0
setuptools                39.1.0                   py27_0
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py27_2
singledispatch            3.4.0.3          py27h9bcb476_0
sip                       4.19.8           py27hf484d3e_0
six                       1.11.0           py27h5f960f1_1
snappy                    1.1.7                hbae5bb6_3
snowballstemmer           1.2.1            py27h44e2768_0
sortedcollections         0.6.1                    py27_0
sortedcontainers          1.5.10                   py27_0
sphinx                    1.7.4                    py27_0
sphinxcontrib             1.0              py27h1512b58_1
sphinxcontrib-websupport  1.0.1            py27hf906f22_1
spyder                    3.2.8                    py27_0
sqlalchemy                1.2.7            py27h6b74fdf_0
sqlite                    3.23.1               he433501_0
ssl_match_hostname        3.5.0.1          py27h4ec10b9_2
statsmodels               0.9.0            py27h3010b51_0
subprocess32              3.5.0            py27h14c3975_0
sympy                     1.1.1            py27hc28188a_0
tblib                     1.3.2            py27h51fe5ba_0
terminado                 0.8.1                    py27_1
testpath                  0.3.1            py27hc38d2c4_0
tk                        8.6.7                hc745277_3
toolz                     0.9.0                    py27_0
tornado                   5.0.2                    py27_0
traitlets                 4.3.2            py27hd6ce930_0
typing                    3.6.4                    py27_0
unicodecsv                0.14.1           py27h5062da9_0
unixodbc                  2.3.6                h1bed415_0
urllib3                   1.22             py27ha55213b_0
wcwidth                   0.1.7            py27h9e3e1ab_0
webencodings              0.5.1            py27hff10b21_1
werkzeug                  0.14.1                   py27_0
wheel                     0.31.1                   py27_0
widgetsnbextension        3.2.1                    py27_0
wrapt                     1.10.11          py27h04f6869_0
xlrd                      1.1.0            py27ha77178f_1
xlsxwriter                1.0.4                    py27_0
xlwt                      1.3.0            py27h3d85d97_0
xz                        5.2.4                h14c3975_4
yaml                      0.1.7                had09818_2
zeromq                    4.2.5                h439df22_0
zict                      0.1.3            py27h12c336c_0
zlib                      1.2.11               ha838bed_2

Comment: Try `pip install gnureadline` ...?

Answer (score 0):

This steps works for me:

Jupyter Instance

- !source activate python3( or other env. , **not root** )
- !conda config --remove channels defaults
- !conda config --add channels conda-forge
- !conda install "your library"
- !conda list
- import "your library"